# Angularjs Amchart map control is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, module, amcharts

I have created directory for the amchart, however, it doesn't work if I remove the empty dependency bracket from the module.

Here is my code.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
   .bar{
        height:10px;
        background-color:blue;
        border-bottom:1px solid white;
        color:white;
        font:9px Arial;
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:10px;
    }
</style>
```

This is test

```
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="OtherController">
  <ul data-ng-repeat="name in customer">
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
```

This code work if I keep this line like this,

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
```

it doesnt work if I remove the brackets and keep it like this,

```
var app=angular.module('app');









     app.directive ('helloWorld',function (){
       function link (scope, element, attr){


           scope.testname="nirav";
         var latlong = {};
latlong["AD"] = {
    "latitude": 42.5,
    "longitude": 1.5
};
latlong["AE"] = {
    "latitude": 24,
    "longitude": 54
};
latlong["AF"] = {
    "latitude": 33,
    "longitude": 65
};

var mapData = [{
    "code": "AD",
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "value": 32358260,
    "color": "#eea638"
}, {
    "code": "AE",
    "name": "Albania",
    "value": 3215988,
    "color": "#d8854f"
}, {
    "code": "AF",
    "name": "Algeria",
    "value": 35980193,
    "color": "#de4c4f"
}];

       var map;
var min = Infinity;
var max = -Infinity;


// get min and max values
for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {

    var value = mapData[i].value;
    if (value < min) {
        min = value;
    }
    if (value > max) {
        max = value;
    }
}





       AmCharts.ready(function() {
    AmCharts.theme = AmCharts.themes.dark;
    map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
    map.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";

    map.addTitle("Population of the World in 2011", 14);
    map.addTitle("source: Gapminder", 11);
    map.areasSettings = {
        unlistedAreasColor: "#000000",
        unlistedAreasAlpha: 0.1
    };
    map.imagesSettings.balloonText = "<span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[title]]</b>: [[value]]</span>";

    var dataProvider = {
        mapVar: AmCharts.maps.worldLow,
        images: []
    }

    var minBulletSize = 6;
    var maxBulletSize = 70;    
    // it's better to use circle square to show difference between values, not a radius
    var maxSquare = maxBulletSize * maxBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;
    var minSquare = minBulletSize * minBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;

    // create circle for each country
    for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
        var dataItem = mapData[i];
        var value = dataItem.value;
        // calculate size of a bubble
        var square = (value - min) / (max - min) * (maxSquare - minSquare) + minSquare;
        if (square < minSquare) {
            square = minSquare;
        }
        var size = Math.sqrt(square / (Math.PI * 2));
        var id = dataItem.code;

        dataProvider.images.push({
            type: "circle",
            width: size,
            height: size,
            color: dataItem.color,
            longitude: latlong[id].longitude,
            latitude: latlong[id].latitude,
            title: dataItem.name,
            value: value
        });
    }





    map.dataProvider = dataProvider;

    map.write("chartdiv");
});


       }
       return {
         template:' <div id="chartdiv">{{testname}}</div>   ',
         link:link,
         restrict:'E'
       }

     });



    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: var app=angular.module('app',[]); is the right syntax

Comment: If you don't include an array of dependencies in the call to angular.module() it will try to find an existing module instead of creating a new module. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
            angular.module('thirdParty1', []).factory('hello', function () {
              return 'hello world';
            });
            angular.module('thirdParty2', []).factory('hello', function () {
              return 'hi there';
            });

            // "own" modules
            angular.module('own1', ['thirdParty1']).controller('Own1Ctrl', function(hello) {
              this.greet = hello;
            });
            angular.module('own2', ['thirdParty2']).controller('Own2Ctrl', function(hello) {
              this.greet = hello;
            });

            angular.module('app', ['own1', 'own2']);



            <body ng-app="app">
              <div ng-controller="Own1Ctrl as own1">
                OwnCtrl1: {{ own1.greet }}
              </div>
              <div ng-controller="Own2Ctrl as own2">
                OwnCtrl2: {{ own2.greet }}
              </div>
            </body>
```

source:
http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2015/05/21/angular-dependencies-naming-clash/

Answer (score 1):

The [] is to instantiate a module, and without it is to retrieve your module. Inside the square brackets are where your dependencies go. If you have no dependencies, just leave it as an empty array, and everything should be fine.

Note: There should only be one instance of the angular.module('name', []) throughout your code. After it is instantiated you will retrieve it without the square brackets.